# If theme folder contains no html.tpl.php file, which html.tpl.php would Drupal default to using?

Tags: theming

I’ve taken over a site wherein the theme folder does not contain any html.tpl.php. In this case, which html.tpl.php would get used?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, it's in

mysite/modules/system/html.tpl.php